# Fragment replace() not replacing all fragments

Tags: android, replace, addition, fragment

If I call add() for fragments A and B with the same viewId and then try to call replace() on that viewId with fragment C, only fragment A is getting removed, ending up with fragments B and C. According to the docs, BOTH A and B should be replaced by C...or am I reading the docs wrong?

Here's one combination that does this:

```
public class FragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, new FragmentA()).add(R.id.fragment, new FragmentB()).commit();

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.swap)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, new FragmentC()).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just added a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs, .replace calls a method that takes a fragment as a parameter.  So I would guess that it is only meant to replace one fragment.  I don't really understand why you would add two fragments to the same id in the first place.

Comment: I was going by the write-up for replace() that says:

This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) **for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId** and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

Comment: My apologies, I did miss that and I mis-interpreted the class definition.  From a too-quick glance.