# How to pop fragment off backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have an activity A, which calls fragment Bf, which calls fragment Cf.  I want Bf to be placed in the backstack when Cf is called so that users can navigate back to it.  However, if a specific button is pressed in Cf, I would like Bf to be removed from the backstack.  Is this possible?

I see that there is a popBackStack() function.  However, I am a little confused on how this would work.  Is it safe to use this function?  Is there any possibility that an activity from a different application would be inserted after Bf on the backstack?

Also, is there any way to alter the savedInstanceState of the fragment on the backstack?

I just can't figure out how to do a robust test on the backstack using the emulator.

Comment: Avoid using back stacks! it doesn't really help with the overall efficiency! use plain replace() or even better remove/add every time you want to navigate! Check my post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802141/is-this-the-right-way-to-clean-up-fragment-back-stack-when-leaving-a-deeply-nest/26093368#26093368

Comment: @stack_ved not a good idea. BackStacks are a great thing. Btw I can't see your post. I guess it was downvoted. :P

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can pop the fragment by name. While adding fragments to the back stack, just give them a name.

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragB");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragC");
```

Then in Fragment_C, pop the back stack using the name ie.. `fragB` and include `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE`

```
someButtonInC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack ("fragB", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
});
```

Comment: It will work even if we pass no parameters too in the fm.popBackStack Method.  fm.popBackStack();

Comment: what if I want to make it on back button press?

Comment: @Akki if you are using add to backstack it will already pop the last fragment added when you hit the back navigation item. So no extra steps are necessary to perform a normal navigation back. Only time you need to override on back button pressed is when you want to do something other than a normal one step back navigation.

Comment: What if that fragment was the first fragment, then `addToBackStack` with `replace` will cause a problem. Any way to do this without calling `addToBackStack`?

Comment: According to doc "all states up to that state will be popped", not just a specific fragment.

Comment: @VahidGhadiri That is how the Stack Data structure is designed.

Answer (score 27):

**Three ways to pop Fragment off BackStack**

Simply add any of these lines:

1)

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

2)

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

3)

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

They're all easy ways to pop fragment off Backstack

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhh! After overiding onbackpressed, this really helped me to go back. I searched for about an hour

Answer (score 3):

**You can try this way**

```
val fm= parentFragmentManager
fm.popBackStack("group", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

Answer (score 1):

first replacing fragment container_view that time we add name as like "Later Transaction"

```
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_view, 
    profileFragment, "Profile").addToBackStack("Later Transaction").commit();
```

then on back press button pop the back stack using the Later Transaction name

```
     int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if(count > 1) {
     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("Later Transaction", 
     FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    } else {
        DialogUtils.show(HomeActivity.this, 
        getString(R.string.exit_app_message), getString(R.string.alert), 
       "Yes","No", new DialogUtils.ActionListner() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveAction() {
                finish();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNegativeAction() {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Great solution for manage back stack entry count of fragments

Answer (score 0):

Here's example to pop last fragment using `BackStackEntry`

```
val manager = supportFragmentManager
try {
    // get last entry (you can get another if needed)
    val entry = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(manager.backStackEntryCount - 1)
    // you can pop it by name
    manager.popBackStack(entry.name, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
    // or pop by id
    manager.popBackStack(entry.id, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    ex.printStackTrace()
}
```