# Can not add to Fragment Back Stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragmenttransaction

I open "Activity A".  "Activity A" immediately does a `FragmentTransaction` like this to Open "Fragment A":

```
FragmentTransaction t = fm.beginTransaction();
ListFragment f = new ProfileFragment();
t.replace(R.id.main_frag, f, "act_frag");
f.setArguments(args);
t.commit();
```

"Fragment A" has a button on it that I would like to open a new `Fragment` ("Fragment B"), but keep the "Fragment A" in the backstack -- so if the user hits back, it is still around.  So I do this:

```
FragmentTransaction t = fm.beginTransaction();
ListFragment f = new FollowFragment();
String username = tvUser.getText().toString();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("follow", "watching");
args.putString("userprofile", username);
args.putInt("userIdprofile", userId);
f.setArguments(args);
t.replace(R.id.main_frag, f, "watching_frag");
t.addToBackStack("watching_frag");
t.commit();
```

I thought by adding `t.addToBackStack(null);` would do the trick; and I have done it before like that.  But instead, when user hit's back, it simply closes "Activity A".

Comment: Refer my ans... <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971780/how-to-pop-fragment-off-backstack#51588700>

Comment: Refer My Answer... <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971780/how-to-pop-fragment-off-backstack#51588700>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when the back button is pressed, the activity is closed. I think for what you are trying to do, you'll have to override the method onBackPressed and add code to handle that
for example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        fm.popBackStack();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

This way, when back is pressed, it'll first check if there are any backstack entries and popback when back is pressed, if not, the default action is called.

Comment: Wait.. is the fragment transaction for adding 'Fragment B' occurring within 'Fragment A' or the Activity?

Comment: It is recurring in Fragment B.  Now that I think about it, that isn't always best practice if I recall.  (`Fragments` communicating to each other).  But the point of what I need still stands regardless of that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting some value inside t.addtoBackStack instead of just null?
I can't test it right now but I think that might be your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work; I changed the code above to reflect what I did.

Comment: Well that's odd. I tested your code and it works just fine. Are you by any chance overriding onBackPressed()?