# Add fragment into backstack behind the topmost/showing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wonder if there's a way to add a fragment into the backstack just behind the showing fragment. So that when a user press "back button" the added fragment would show up to the user.

Comment: FragmentManager not contains such methods. Why you can't catch onBackPressed and show desired fragment when current closed?

Answer (score 0):

***As per my knowledge I am not sure the `Fragment Manager` can do such things !***

**Step-1**: `Why don't you add the fragment to`backStack` when mounting the fragment to the container

**Step-2**: Next `onBackpressed`or `click of any view` just pop the fragment from the container

---

**[Here is a sample from another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14973554/1083093)**

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragB");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragC");
Then in Fragment_C, pop the back stack using the name ie.. fragB and include POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE

    someButtonInC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack ("fragB", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    });
```