# Accessing the same fragment from a button and menu item JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have two questions and your help is really appreciated

**First:**

is there a way to make a button in the main activity and a menu item open the same fragment from back stack without creating a new one.

**Second:**

how can I retain what is typed in `editText` in the fragment without any buttons clicked, should I use `outState.putString()` in the `onSaveInstantState()` method or somewhere else and then do I check if it existed should I do it in the `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: yes, you can, just use similar code in button onClick and onOptionsItemSelected
[pop the fragment by name example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14973554/2092850)
Second: [Save fragment state example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6787393/2092850)